# Is it possible for me to load a preview image at its original size when viewing a preview (BeautifulSoup Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, youtube

Prefacing this with a new guy warning and whatnot. I'm currently trying to scrape images off of youtube for a personal challenge project, specifically images in the community tab of certain channels. I wanted to make a script with the ability to download each of the images used in the community tab. So far I have hit a few hiccups but at this point I have somewhat functioning code that will download the first handful of images from the screen (I know I can implement the scroll feature from selenium but I'm not focusing on that yet).

I have managed to scrape all the urls for the images on the page, but turns out they're all 600x600 px and not the original image. I'm not sure what the exact terminology for these but I'm just going to refer to them as preview images. Unfortunately I don't see any easy options within bs4 to find the original images, but I have a couple ideas that I'm just quite sure how to implement.

The first idea is that if I click on the image on the page it loads me to another url with the original image, and I fetch the url and download it no problem. Only issue is I can't seem to find a way for my code to open the page to download the original from as I can't find the link to it within the html. However, this is my second day ever trying to look through html so I very well could be missing something easy here. If I could, I imagine implementation into my current code would be quite easy as I would just need to loop through each of the images.

Secondly, I have an addon named "Hoverzoom" for my browser that shows me the original image when hovering my cursor over the preview. This is a little bit out there, but I reckon there is some sort of way to directly find the original image from a preview if this addon can do it, but I am at a lost for any libraries or code that could do so.

Attaching my code below, any help is much appreciated! I know some of my code is a little weird but I couldn't find an easier way to download images as sometimes the fetched url would lack "https:" and I am unsure how to fix it in an elegant manner. If you have an idea on how I could fix this up a bit I would love it! Thanks again!

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request as req

site = 'https://www.youtube.com/c/tolariancommunity/community'
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/pictures/'
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img',{"src":True})
urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]
defective_urls = []
res = []
for i in urls:
    if i not in res:
        res.append(i)
urls = res
for i in urls:
    if i.startswith("https://"):
        pass
    else:
        defective_urls = defective_urls + [i]
        urls.remove(i)
defective_urls[:] = [s.replace('//', 'https://') for s in defective_urls]
urls = urls + defective_urls
count = 1
for i in urls:
    req.urlretrieve(i, "%s.png" % count)
    count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking this image for example:

https://yt3.ggpht.com/hyDJwLOZcpo5QJQCCrg8FxCZvV7LsMK1G43SibcPzP8eqshsSkSCB5s44CtKXZJrZhh8zFGOSaMD=s679-c-fcrop64=1,421a0000bfb2ffff-nd

It opens a `679 x679`

It seems you can control the size using what comes after `=` in the URL.

`s679-c-fcrop64=1,421a0000bfb2ffff-nd`

You can strip it down to just: `s679` and you get the same image.

If you change `679` to `2000` e.g.

https://yt3.ggpht.com/hyDJwLOZcpo5QJQCCrg8FxCZvV7LsMK1G43SibcPzP8eqshsSkSCB5s44CtKXZJrZhh8zFGOSaMD=s2000

You get the same image but with a size of `1384 x 679` pixels.

So it looks like this `s` value is used and it returns the nearest sized match.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help, I really appreciate it! Been working on it for hours but this is much simpler to work with than my solution, thanks again!